# How to make a food item in Minetest do multiple actions? [Minetest][Modding]

Tags: lua, minetest

I'm making mods for the game MineClone2 (a downloadable game for [Minetest](https://minetest.net))
Currently, I am trying to make a food item that will boost speed as well as add be eaten. My issue is that if I use this code

```
minetest.register_craftitem("hot_chocolate_mod:hot_chocolate", {
description = "Cup of Hot Chocolate",
inventory_image = "hot_chocolate_mod_hot_chocolate.png",
        groups = { craftitem = 1, food = 3, eatable = 6, can_eat_when_full=1 },
        
on_left_click = minetest.item_eat(6),
on_use = function(name, param, hp_change)
local hp_change = 2
        
    local player = minetest.get_player_by_name("singleplayer")
    
    player:set_physics_override({
        speed = 3 -- set gravity to 10% of its original value
                   -- (0.1 * 9.81)
    })
    
    player:set_hp(player:get_hp() + hp_change)
    minetest.item_eat(hp, "mcl_buckets:bucket_empty 1")
    end
 
    })
```

It will add health to the player, as well as a speed boost, but is for some (probably obvious) reason not ever disappearing. I think that this is caused by adding health, so it never gets "eaten". My question is how to make someone eat an item as well as get a speed boost.
My desired behavior is that if the player has one of these items, and they left click, then they will eat the item, get a temporary speed boost, and then the item will be gone.

The tutorial I'm using:
[tutorial](https://minetest.org/modbook/chapters/nodes_items_crafting.html)

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that `minetest.item_eat` doesn't eat the item, but instead, it creates an eat function and returns the function. If it would eat the item, then `on_left_click = minetest.item_eat(6)` wouldn't make sense because it would eat the item when the script was loaded and not when the player would left-click.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for your response. I think you're probably correct about the `minetest.item_eat()` do you have any ideas on how to eat it within the function? Because `on_use` and `on_left_click` are (as far as I know) one and the same.

Comment: one idea is to call minetest.item_eat to get the function, then call the function (pretend that you are the game and you're calling on_left_click). Another idea is to find the source code for minetest.item_eat, see what it does, and then copy that.

Comment: You should not use the `minetest.org` modding book; it is a hostile and inofficial copy of rubenwardy's official modding book: https://rubenwardy.com/minetest_modding_book/en/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://minetest.gitlab.io/minetest/) say:

> `minetest.item_eat(hp_change[, replace_with_item])`
>
> - Returns function(itemstack, user, pointed_thing) as a function wrapper for `minetest.do_item_eat`.
> - `replace_with_item` is the itemstring which is added to the inventory.
>   If the player is eating a stack, then `replace_with_item` goes to a
>   different spot.

`on_left_click = minetest.item_eat(6)` would be the correct usage, *if* (1) `on_left_click` was a property of the item definition and (2) you *only* wanted to heal by 6 HP. You want to also increase the speed though.

Cleaning up your code a bit, we obtain:

```lua
local eat_func = minetest.item_eat(6, "mcl_buckets:bucket_empty") -- eat & heal for 6 HP, give empty MCL bucket as replacement item
minetest.register_craftitem("hot_chocolate_mod:hot_chocolate", {
    description = "Cup of Hot Chocolate",
    inventory_image = "hot_chocolate_mod_hot_chocolate.png",
    groups = { food = 3, eatable = 6, can_eat_when_full = 1 },
    on_use = function(itemstack, user, pointed_thing)
        user:set_physics_override({
            speed = 3 -- set 3x speed
        })
        return eat_func(itemstack, user, pointed_thing) -- now eat it
    end
})
```

Note that you need to `return` the return value(s) of `eat_func` since `on_use` returns the item stack after use.

This will call `minetest.registered_on_item_eats` for you without you having to duplicate the `minetest.item_eat` code.

Where to go from here:

1. Clear the speed-up after a set time. You may use e.g. `minetest.after` for this. Note that you'll have to check whether the player is still online.
2. Preserve the speed-up if the player "relogs" (logs out & back in) by storing it in a table.
3. This will currently overwrite speed-up added by other mods; conversely, other mods will probably overwrite this mod's speed-up. Prevent this by using an API mod such as [`player_monoids`](https://content.minetest.net/packages/Byakuren/player_monoids/).

Answer (score -2):

(NOTE: This adds health points, this DOES NOT add hunger points)
I was able to add in a speed boost as well as adding hp using the following code:

```
minetest.register_craftitem("hot_chocolate_mod:hot_chocolate", {
    description = "Cup of Hot Chocolate",
    inventory_image = "hot_chocolate_mod_hot_chocolate.png",
    groups = { food = 3, eatable = 6, can_eat_when_full = 1 },
    on_use = function(itemstack, user, pointed_thing)
        user:set_physics_override({
            speed = 3 -- set 3x speed
        })
        return eat_func(itemstack, user, pointed_thing) -- now eat it
    end
})
```

Comment: No, the modding book code is not as broken as this. This inappropriately writes to global variables (which will trigger warnings), hardcodes singleplayer for no reason, then mixes that with user, has a wrong comment saying it sets gravity although it sets speed instead, and manually copying `minetest.item_eat` code.